# Where to find a content slider - ready made

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow

Already 2 hours I spent on Google to find this content slider. No luck.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeT9I.png

I want the slider can support text, image or video. Then have arrow on left & right. Then have a menu below the slider.

Maybe something like **[this](http://www.binpress.com/)** on real site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called **Anything Slider**: http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

It supports html you so you can virtually put anything in there. Here is the [Demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/)

Answer (score 1):

are you thinking of [easyslider?](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding)

with it working identical to your example at http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.5/05.html

Comment: Thanks.. I tested this one.. Cannot change the numeric on menu to text.

Answer (score 0):

These have

- left/right controls
- navigation
- allow for content/text/image/video

**[Coda Slider 2.0](http://www.ndoherty.biz/2009/10/coda-slider-2/)**

[image: coda slider 2.0]

**[dualSlider](http://www.hugoandcat.com/DualSlider/index.html)**

[image: dualSlider]

Dual Slider seems a little more "beta" than Coda

of the several listings of jQuery sliders these two were found on http://www.ourtuts.com/jquery-slider-plugins/

@ImaStudent and @FatherStorm also answered with good slider's, I think some customization will be necessary given the specifics you're looking for.